# Does definition of Nichush cover Middos based behavior?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avodah-zarah, middos-character-traits, parashat-chaye-sara

The Gemmorah (on [Gen 24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.24.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Talmud&lang2=en)) considers Eliezer's approach to choosing a wife a [forbidden] Nichush.

IIRC it was based on a girl's special [and seemingly rare] virtues and not blind chance. If I was truly frum I could say it for my boys - you marry the first girl of good virtues.

Why in Gemmora's view, does Nichush cover Middos?

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in [Chullin 95b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.95b.8?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Chullin.95b.8.1&lang2=bi) says that if one relied on actions like Eliezer did, then that would violate Nichush. However, Rashi says that is only if one relies solely on the action without any reasoning behind it. See [Tosfos](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Chullin.95b.8.1?lang=bi) there as well who explains that once Eliezer asked about her lineage, there was no longer a prohibition of Nichush [in my understandning, this means that once one looks for an explanation for an action, then it no longer falls under the prohibition of Nichush].

To use your examples, if one married a person based on a specific predicted action without examining the motivation, then yes, that would be Nichush. But determining based on reasons and character traits would not be Nichush.

Comment: THank you, very informative. Could you please quote the Gemmorah and relevant Tosfos and I'd mark it as an accepted answer.